# How to remove duplicate rows in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

In column 'M' i have hundreds of rows with multiple duplicates. I only want one record to show per duplicate when i run my macro. Below is my code and it deletes all records apart from one.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

With ActiveSheet
    Set Rng = Range("M5:M").End(xlDown)
    Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

It starts from M5 as this is where the data is initially. Why would it only be showing one record?

Comment: `Set Rng = Range("M5").End(xlDown)` is one cell.

Comment: Changed it ("M5:M") but still nothing :/

Comment: Note: You should avoid `ActiveSheet` and instead define which sheet you are referencing through it's `CodeName`. Then input a dot (`.`) in front of all references to be explicit, e.g: `.Range(...`

Answer (score 1):

Your original attempt, `Range("M5").End(xlDown)`, is just one cell.

Your new attempt, `Range("M5:M").End(xlDown)`, is closer but not a valid `Range` reference.

Try the following:

```
Set Rng = Range("M5:M" & Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)
```

**EDIT:**

If you're dealing with an entire range, you need to specify the *Columns* argument of [`Range.RemoveDuplicates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates), something like this:

```
Sub RemoveDupes()
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    Range("A5:V" & lastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(13), Header:=xlYes ' column M = 13
End Sub
```

Comment: That removes all the duplicates in that columns which is good! But only column M has the duplicates removed i want the rows to be deleted aswell if that makes sense?

Comment: Then you need to specify the *Columns* argument of [`Range.RemoveDuplicates`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates), and it shouldn't just be column M as the range reference. What column does your data start in and what column does it end in?

Comment: `Debug.Print lastRow`, is it what you want? Can't repro the error.

Comment: I have merged cells above A5 to V5 which is causing the error. ' All merged cells need to be the same size'

Comment: I removed them and still not working, this is frustrating